# Prove or disprove : i) $(\mathbf{S},+,.)\cong (\mathbf{R},+,.)$ (as rings) ii) $(\mathbf{S},+)\cong (\mathbf{R},+)$ (as groups)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

> Let $\mathbf{S}=\left\{\left[\begin{array}{ll}\mathbf{a} & \mathbf{b} \\ 0 & \mathbf{a}\end{array}\right]: \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}\right\}$, $\mathbf{R}=\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

> Prove or disprove :

> i) $(\mathbf{S},+,.)\cong (\mathbf{R},+,.)$ (as rings)

> ii) $(\mathbf{S},+)\cong (\mathbf{R},+)$ (as groups)

I think we have $|\mathbf{S}|=2^3$ but $|\mathbf{R}|=2^2$ so we have $|\mathbf{R}| \neq |\mathbf{S}|$ so $(\mathbf{S},+,.)\ncong (\mathbf{R},+,.)$ but $(\mathbf{R},+)$ is Klein four-group, and every element of $(\mathbf{S},+)$ has order $2$, then $(\mathbf{S},+)\cong (\mathbf{R},+)$ (as groups). Is this true ?

Comment: Why would we have $\left|\mathbf{S}\right|=2^3$? Since there is a one-to-one correspondence between the matrices in $\mathbf{S}$ and the set $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ simply by mapping each $(a,b)$ to the corresponding matrix as in your definition of the set, they have to have the same cardinality of $2^2$.

Comment: It's $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ not $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

Comment: In addition to the problem of computing $|\mathbf{S}|$ incorrectly, **if** we had $|\mathbf{R}| \neq |\mathbf{S}|$ (and again, just to emphasize, this is wrong), then this would imply both $(\mathbf{S}, +, \cdot) \not\cong (\mathbf{R},+,\cdot)$ _and_ $(\mathbf{S},+) \not\cong (\mathbf{R},+)$ (isomorphisms are necessarily bijections)

Comment: @BrianMoehring so $(\mathbf{S},+,.)\cong (\mathbf{R},+,.)$ (as ring) is true  ?

Comment: @1200785626 That's what you need to check.  My comment in no way implies an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ is not isomorphic to $R$ as rings since $S$ has a non-zero nilpotent, while $R$ hasn't. More precisely, there is $x\in S$, $x\ne0$ such that $x^2=0$. Can you find it?

Comment: Yes if we set $a=0,b=1$ we have nillpotent element.

Comment: Why $R$ hasn't  non zero nillpotent elements?

Comment: Did you find one? There are only few tries! For instance, what is $(0,1)^2$?